# Como checar sendo maiúsculo, minúsculo, ou mistura de maiúsculo com minúsculo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    print('-----')
    print('TESTE')
    print('-----')

    print()

    lista = ['Joao', 'Joaozinho', 'Rafael']
    print(lista)
    var = str(input('Digite algum dos nomes da lista:'))

    if var == 'Joao' or var == 'João' or var == 'joao' or var == 'JOao' or var == 'JOAO' or var == 'JOão':
    print('Qualquer coisa')

    elif var == 'Joaozinho' or var == 'JOAOZINHO' or var == 'joaozinho' or var == 'joaoZINHO':
    print('Qualquer coisa')

    elif var == 'RAFAEL' or var == 'Rafael' or var == 'RAfael':
    print('Qualquer coisa')
```

Basicamente, o que eu quero fazer é o seguinte, quero checar esses nomes exemplares sem ter que fazer estas várias condições, por exemplo o "RAFAEL", "Rafael", e "RAfael", mesmo com algumas letras maiúsculas misturadas com minúscula, como por exemplo este último "RAfael", como eu faço isto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não precisa!
Simplesmente converta a variável para *lowercase* (tudo minúsculo) usando `.lower()`, e então compare com a versão em minúsculo do nome.

Assim:

```
if var.lower() == "joao":
    print("Qualquer coisa")
elif var.lower() == "joaozinho":
    print("Qualquer coisa")
elif var.lower() == "rafael":
    print("Qualquer coisa")
```

Comment: Tivemos o mesmo raciocínio hahah

Comment: Obrigado Matheus, resolveu meu problema!

Answer (score 2):

Não entendi exatamente o que deseja, mas tive o mesmo raciocínio do @Matheus Avellar

```
print('-----')
print('TESTE')
print('-----')
print()
lista = ['Joao', 'Joaozinho', 'Rafael']
print(lista)
var = raw_input('Digite algum dos nomes da lista:\n')
print('Voce digitou         =>'+'"'+var+'"'+' tudo misturado minusculo com maisculo'+'\n'+'Mas eu exibo correto =>'+'"'+var.lower().title())+'"'
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/nmYvuE)

Comment: Obrigado também magic!!